# Initialize a structure with NULL values

Tags: c, struct, null-pointer

I have a problem when I'm initializing this structure :

```
struct node {
    int label;
    struct node *lchild;
    struct node *rchild;
}

int main(void) {
    struct node n1;
    n1.label = 1;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is my members `lchild` and `rchild` don't point to NULL.

I can resolve the problem by adding

```
n1.lchild = NULL;
n1.rchild = NULL;
```

But I don't understand why I need to do that?

Comment: So what do they point to instead?

Comment: @Arc676 If I print their address, I have something like that `0x2000000000000000` and `0x7fff7cbd0010`. If I print their label member, I have a segmentation fault.

Comment: Is writing `struct node n1 = { .lchild = NULL}` also boring?

Comment: You create `n1` on the stack; C makes no guarantees about the initial values of stack-allocated variables, and they can and usually will contain random garbage. If you want them to contain specific values, you'll have to take care of that yourself. You could declare a function to do this for you: `struct node* initNode(struct node* newNode)` - sets the fields to their proper initial values and returns the pointer to the same struct.

Comment: @szczurcio Thanks for your explanations, that could be a solution.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't understand why I need to do that

Because the compiler doesn't do it for you.

You could skip this in case you can make sure the members aren't read before having been written to.

Comment: Alright, I thought all members are initialized with their default value, so pointers with null value. I will write a function to initialise this struct.

Comment: There are no "default"-values on C. @mathieu_b

Comment: Trivial edit since I accidentally downvoted this! Have an upvote now.

Answer (score 7):

The members of an automatic storage object such as `n1` do not get zero-initialized automatically (See C11 standard, **6.7.9.10**). You have to do this yourself.

You can take care of this easily by suitably initializing `n1`:

```
struct node n1 = {1};
```

This will set the first member to `1` and will zero-initialize the rest, meaning the pointers get initialized to `NULL`. You can be more explicit if you wish:

```
struct node n1 = {1, NULL, NULL};
```

---

References:

From the C11 standard, **6.7.9 Initialization**:

> 21. If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in
>       a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>       are elements in the array, *the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>       initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>       duration*.

And, previously in the same section,

> 10. ... If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>      — if it has pointer type, it is
>       *initialized to a null pointer*;

(emphasis mine)

Comment: The the null-pointer not necessarily is represented by `0`s. So using `memset()` (or any other approach initialising with `0`) might mostly work, but isn't portable.

Comment: @alk I didn't say anything about `memset`. But are you sure zero-initialization of a pointer type is not guaranteed to `NULL` initialize it?

Comment: Right, you didn't ,copypasta bs from my side. Sry!

Comment: I think the standard doesn't guarantee that `NULL == 0`, which is what @alk meant.

Comment: @szczurcio That is definitely true. But it doesn't mean that zero initializing a pointer isn't guaranteed to set it to `NULL`. I think it is, but not 100% sure. Looking it up.

Comment: I am not sure about initialisers, need to check the Standard. Using `memset()`, as well as `calloc()` to initialise pointers to `NULL`, however is not portable to any platform which does not use the value of `0` to represent a null-pointer.

Comment: @alk Yes, that makes sense (the `memset`/`calloc` thing)

Comment: I am **not** referring to any operation involving the assignment operator.

Comment: `= {1}` is fine: N1570 6.7.9.21  *"If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
of an aggregate, ... , the remainder of the aggregate shall be
initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."*

Comment: @user694733 Thx for double checking this. So my claim does **not** apply to initialisers. :-}

Comment: And about static storage duration initialization: 6.7.9.10 *"... And If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then: 
— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; ..."*

Comment: @user694733 Thanks. I put the relevant quotes in references (C11 standard)

Comment: For completeness, the link to the C11 Standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9